# Trying to boot install medium results in error: "import_mok_state() falied: Volume Full"

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I'm having trouble booting to the live ISO while trying to install ubuntu-budgie. Booting of the USB results in:

```
Could not create MokListRT: Volume Full
Could not create MokListXRT: Volume Full
Could not create SbatLevelRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
```

I have tried:

- Reflashing the live USB
- Disabling Secure Boot

The live USB does not encounter this error while booting it of another machine, I suspect some setting should be toggled from UEFI?

If anyone has any idea what might cause these errors any direction would be greatly appreciated :)